# Linux Directory Size Limiting

Tags: limit, size, quota, vsftp

I have a FTP server with anonymous access for my local network. Here I have directories named with department names. I want to limit the directory sizes in respect to departments.

```
/var/ftp/pub/
            X Company/
                     Dept 1/
                     Dept 2/
                     Dept 3/
```

I want to limit Dept 1 directory with 50 GB, Dept 2 with 20 GB and Dept 3 20 GB.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: What filesystem do you have on your server? IIRC, xfs has "project quotas" that can apply to directory trees. (I assume the worst case, i.e. your uploaders don't have individual accounts or can be in several departments at the same time, i.e. you can't do per-user or per-group quota.)

Comment: Filesystem XFS. My uploaders don't have individual accounts, they use anonymous access, in that case I need quota on directory instead of user or group.